Failing to run HWASan build on Android: dlopen failed: TLS symbol "(null)"
I've followed the instructions over on https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/hwasan to enable HWASan for my app:

I switched to using a shared libc++
I've added target_compile_options(${TARGET} PUBLIC -fsanitize=hwaddress -fno-omit-frame-pointer) target_link_options(${TARGET} PUBLIC -fsanitize=hwaddress) to the CMakeLists.txt.
I only build for arm64-v8a
I added useLegacyPackaging = true
I added debuggable true
I added app/src/main/resources/lib/wrap.sh

A few sanity checks to make sure that I enabled HWAsan correctly:

Without the target_compile_options and target_link_options lines, the app runs properly.
The apk contains libc++_shared.so, showing I correctly enabled shared libc++
The apk contains /lib/wrap.sh
The app uses a single .so: libfoobar.so, and readelf -d libfoobar.so  | grep NEEDED prints:

0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libclang_rt.hwasan-aarch64-android.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libandroid.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [liblog.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libEGL.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libOpenSLES.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc++_shared.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libGLESv2.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so]

When I run the apk on my Pixel 7 with Android 14, the following error happens:
dlopen failed: TLS symbol "(null)" in dlopened "/apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libclang_rt.hwasan-aarch64-android.so"
Full error:
09-13 21:43:19.312 28028 28028 D nativeloader: Load /data/app/~~VeP7A7hHnvshxaanDdLEyQ==/com.qux-GBK8s7jkWQ4TXb2mglMtUA==/lib/arm64/libfoobar.so using ns clns-4 from class loader (caller=/data/app/~~VeP7A7hHnvshxaanDdLEyQ==/com.qux-GBK8s7jkWQ4TXb2mglMtUA==/base.apk!classes2.dex): dlopen failed: TLS symbol "(null)" in dlopened "/apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libclang_rt.hwasan-aarch64-android.so" referenced from "/apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libclang_rt.hwasan-aarch64-android.so" using IE access model

My .so does not do any funny business regarding TLS. I disabled all exotic compilation flags. I bumped the minSdk to 29 out of an abundance of caution.
Any clue as to what is going on?
